# Add document symbol hierarchy on a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm developing a vscode extension and I want to add a `DocumentSymbolProvider` that displays the symbol hierarchy. But for some unknown reason the following instance code isn't working:

```typescript
const documentSymbolProvider: DocumentSymbolProvider = {
  provideDocumentSymbols(document) {
    const symbolsTest: DocumentSymbol = {
      name: 'test',
      detail: 'details',
      kind: SymbolKind.Boolean,
      range: new Range(new Position(0, 0), new Position(0, 10)),
      selectionRange: new Range(new Position(0, 0), new Position(0, 10)),
      children: [
        {
          name: 'child',
          detail: 'child details',
          kind: SymbolKind.Array,
          range: new Range(new Position(0, 11), new Position(0, 15)),
          selectionRange: new Range(new Position(0, 11), new Position(0, 15)),
          children: [],
        },
      ],
    }
    
    return [symbolsTest]
  },
}
```

I set two hardcoded symbols, but vscode won't display both.

How should I use this API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because I was creating the objects `DocumentSymbol` using plain `{ }` instead of `new` operator - and is necessary to create using `new` in order to inherit.

Code fixed:

```typescript
const symbolsTest1 = new DocumentSymbol(
  'test',
  'details',
  SymbolKind.Boolean,
  new Range(new Position(0, 0), new Position(0, 15)),
  new Range(new Position(0, 0), new Position(0, 15))
)
symbolsTest1.children = [
  new DocumentSymbol(
    'child',
    'child details',
    SymbolKind.Array,
    new Range(new Position(0, 11), new Position(0, 15)),
    new Range(new Position(0, 11), new Position(0, 15))
  ),
]
```